# Change all keys in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to know if there is any way to change all the keys of a dictionary without creating a loop

for example if I have a dictionary :

```
Dictionary <DateTime, bool> dates
```

and I decrease a day in each key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ extensions:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, bool> dates = new Dictionary<DateTime, bool>()
{
    {
        DateTime.Now, true
    }
};

var modifiedDic = dates.ToDictionary(z => z.Key.AddDays(-1), z => z.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to modify and then convert back to Ditionary

```
var newDates = dates.ToDictionary(dic => dic.Key.AddDays(-1), dic => dic.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use linq:

```
dates = dates.ToDictionary(i => i.Key.AddDays(-1), i => i.Value);
```

Good luck with your quest.